# SQLConfigDataSource does not add System DSN for 64-bit drivers

Tags: c++, dll, odbc, 64-bit

I load the odbccp32.dll from `System32` and even tried to use from `SysWow64`. I use `SQLConfigDataSource` function to configure my System DSN for specified Driver. This function successfully configure drivers which are 32-bit, but does not do the same  for 64-bit drivers. Does this `dll` only works for drivers which are 32-bit? When I ran ODBC  Administrator tool (64-bit) I am able to see the 64-bit drivers and add them manually to System DSN, but I cannot do this using this `DLL`.

Answer (score 1):

Only 64-bit applications can configure a 64-bit datasource using `SQLConfigDataSource`. If you application is targeting 32-bit Windows, it will modify the 32-bit data sources when calling this function. You need to configure the data source in a different way (from a 64-bit application, from the command line, modify the registry directly, etc.)

Comment: I already have the driver version which is 64-bit and I just want to add this ODBC driver as 64-bit but I am not able to do that. Let's I am able to add different windows odbc driver as 32-bit but cannot add 64-bit driver. It's looks like the .dll cannot find it. Or did you mean that when I am using 64-bit odbc drivers I am unable to configure any 32-bit.

Comment: @overkail: Is you application calling `SQLConfigDataSource` 32-bit or 64-bit? If it's 32-bit it's only going to be able to configure 32-bit data sources.

Comment: I use 64-bit dll I think, because I point directly to C:\Windows\System32\odbccp32.dll. My OS is 64-bit.

Comment: @overkail: RIght, but if the compiled application that is calling `SQLConfigDataSource` is a 32-bit application, it cannot register a 64-bit data source.

Comment: I see, but is there any workaround for that than compiling the application which is calling that to 64 bit? It's old application written in InstallShield 6.x.

Comment: @overkail: I guess you could shell out to syswow64\odbcconf , or write a 64-bit application and invoke that separately

Comment: I see, yes I checked it out and it seems to be working correctly. Thanks ;)